# Can anyone identify this brick?

Tags: part-identification

[image]I don’t see a part code on it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21):

That's [32177 Technic Beam 1x7 with Fan](https://rebrickable.com/parts/32177/technic-beam-1-x-7-with-fan/15/).

[image: Part photo]

Answer (score 5):

If you increase contrast, you can read LEGO on the middle bar. Maybe there is also a hard to read number on the back side?

[image]